# What does this initializer list mean?

Tags: c++

```
// Use multiple inheritance. We want 
// both a string and an Object:
class MyString: public string, public Object {
public:
  ~MyString() {
    cout << "deleting string: " << *this << endl;
  }
  MyString(string s) : string(s) {}
};
```

For the above code, I do not understand what `string(s)` mean? There is no variable called `string` in fact, but why it can work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The question you linked to is about member initialization, in this case, the base-class-constructor is called. As the OP mentioned, there is no member called string.

Comment: Just to say, you probably don't want to derive from `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, when constructing a derived class, the default base-constructor (if it exists) will be called. If you want to explicitly call a different base-constructor for a certain derived-constructor, you can do this using the initializer list.

In this case, when constructing `MyString`, the `string`-constructor which takes a `string` as its only argument (the copy constructor), will be called with `s` as the argument.

Comment: I seem to vaguely recall that it's a C++11 feature. Right or not? Is there a specific term for it (besides "initializer list" which usually refers to initializing fields)?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's the only way to call a base-constructor, and it's been around for quite some time. I think what you're remembering is the fact that all member initializations now have to be done in constructors (initializer list or body, but not at declaration, as in `int member=3`).

Answer (score 2):

The `string(s)` is constructing the parent class instance of `MyString` with `s`.

Note that `MyString` inherits from `string`, this is what that use of `string` refers to.

This is known as an "initializer list".

Answer (score 1):

It initialises the parent subobject of type `string`. In effect, it specifies which parent constructor to call for the `string` parent.

Answer (score 1):

`MyString` derives from `string`. The syntax you refer to, `string(s)`, calls the base class constructor with `s` as the sole argument.